# How K-Fold Prevents overfitting in a model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, cross-validation, supervised-learning

I am training a Multi-layer Perceptron . I have two questions first one is that How can K fold prevents Overfitting because train-test-split also do same thing that take the training part and validate the model , same as for K fold instead of just there are multiple folds . But there is a chance of overfitting in train_test_split , then how K fold prevents it , because in my perception model could also gets overfit into train part of K fold what you think ? 
Second Question is that i am getting 95% + accuracy from K fold , i have been told by sir that there is too much variance , how it is possible here because k fold resolves this overfitting?

Comment: K-Fold Cross validation does not prevent overfitting

Comment: It means that 95 % plus accuracy says that i am in overfitting , if yes then how to resolves it ? @Matias Valdenegro

Comment: You are asking too broad questions, nobody can tell you if "95%+" accuracy is overfitting, there is missing information.

Comment: Short answer: it does not (as @MatiasValdenegro has noted already).

Answer (score 5):

K-Fold cross-validation won't reduce overfitting on its own, but using it will generally give you a better insight on your model, which eventually can help you avoid or reduce overfitting.

Using a simple training/validation split, the model may perform well if the way the split isn't indicative of the true data distribution. K-Fold cross-validation splits the data into `k` chunks & performs training `k` times, by using a particular chunk as the validation set & the rest of the chunks as the training set. Therefore, the model may perform quite well on some training fold, but relatively worse on other training folds. This will give you a better indication of how well the model truly performs.

If a relatively high training accuracy is attained but a substantially lower validation accuracy indicates overfitting (high variance & low bias). The goal would be to keep both variance & bias at low levels, potentially at the expense of slightly worse training accuracy, as this would indicate that the learnt model has generalised well to unseen instances. You can read more on the [bias vs variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).

Choosing the number of folds may also play a part in this insight, as explained in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27744). Depending on the size of the data, the training folds being used may be too large compared to the validation data.

Comment: Cross-validation (CV) in itself neither reduces overfitting nor optimizes anything. The term "overfitting" does not appear anywhere in the thread you have linked (save for the heavily downvoted answer). "*if the model overfits on a particular training fold*" the other folds will not counteract anything. Your 3rd para has nothing to do with CV, in which normally one never sees the *training* accuracy (only the ones in the validation folds). I kindly suggest you focus more on the subject, as you sound somewhat confused.

Comment: @desertnaut Yes you are right, what I meant was that it gives a better indication about overfitting & I've updated my answer to reflect this. I've mentioned the training accuracy to explain how a model can have "too much variance" even though a relatively high performance is attained.

Comment: Retracted the downvote after editing a little more your answer. Please keep in mind that what we mean means nothing if we don't expose it clearly and precisely for others; try to get to the OP's shoes, who has used CV because everyone seemed to advise them that it (magically?) reduces overfitting, and is now justifiably puzzled ("*I have applied CV, how I can still overfit?*")

Answer (score -1):

K fold can help with overfitting because you essentially split your data into various different train test splits compared to doing it once. By running the train test splits on multiple different sets as opposed to just one, you get a better understanding of how your model is actually performing on the dataset and unseen data. It doesn’t completely prevent it and it all boils down to your data at the end of the day (if the data you have training, testing and validating is not truly representative of future points you can still end up with an overfit model).